# Problems with Android data model

Tags: android

When I try loading another activity, I keep getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. So when I get to my code, it just fails. Here is the offending code:

```
package com.example.lasic;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class QuestionActivity extends Activity{
    private int counter = 0;
    private UserScanner scanner;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.firstq);
        scanner = new UserScanner();
        loadNext();
    }
    public void loadNext() {
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setText(scanner.left.get(counter));
        TextView view1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        view1.setText(scanner.questionList.get(counter));
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setText(scanner.centerLeft.get(counter));
        Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button3.setText(scanner.center.get(counter));
        Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button4.setText(scanner.centerRight.get(counter));
        Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        button5.setText(scanner.right.get(counter));
        counter = counter + 1;
    }
}
```

I have tested the UserScanner class and it works as I intended. It contains the data in five ArrayLists(left, center, centerLeft, right, centerRight), which I know are populated correctly as I want them to be. Yet when I run the Android program, I get the following logcat error

```
02-17 14:28:20.307: E/AndroidRuntime(1245): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
02-17 14:28:20.307: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
02-17 14:28:20.307: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
02-17 14:28:20.307: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at com.example.lasic.QuestionActivity.loadNext(QuestionActivity.java:21)
02-17 14:28:20.307: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at com.example.lasic.QuestionActivity.onCreate(QuestionActivity.java:17)
02-17 14:28:20.307: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
02-17 14:28:20.307: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-17 14:28:20.307: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
02-17 14:28:20.307: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     ... 11 more



 package com.example.lasic;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import android.os.Parcelable;

public class UserScanner {
    private ArrayList<String> strings;
    private ArrayList<String> questionList;
    private ArrayList<String> left;
    private ArrayList<String> centerLeft;
    private ArrayList<String> center;
    private ArrayList<String> right;
    private ArrayList<String> centerRight;
    public UserScanner(){
        this.strings = InsertionSort.laser();
        this.questionList = new ArrayList<String>(20);
        this.left = new ArrayList<String>(20);
        this.centerLeft = new ArrayList<String>(20);
        this.center = new ArrayList<String>(20);
        this.centerRight = new ArrayList<String>(20);
        this.right = new ArrayList<String>(20);
        for(String x: strings) {
          if (x.contains("M:")) {
        center.add(x);
       }
           else if (x.contains("CL:")) {
        centerLeft.add(x);
        } 
           else if (x.contains("CR:")) {
        centerRight.add(x);
        }
            else if (x.contains("L:")) {
                left.add(x);
        } 
        else if (x.contains("R:")) {
        right.add(x);
        }
        else if (x.contains("?")) {
            questionList.add(x);
       }
    }

    }
    public ArrayList<String> getLeft(){
         return left;
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getList() {
        return questionList; 
    }
    }
```

So while the scanner is initialized with the appropriate data, the arraylists here are empty and of size 0. So how do I solve this problem?

Comment: It's always as "simple" as it looks. They are in fact not populated correctly. Do you populate them in the constructor?

Comment: Yes I did do that. I've tested the UserScanner out and it works just fine.

Comment: Then your test is flawed somehow. After running the constructor in the code above, `left` is empty.

Comment: I've tried everything, even making separate instance variables for the activity and public getters and setters but still no luck

Comment: Sounds strange. But my guess is still that the problem lies in UserScanner somehow. Since it isn't null. You might want to post the code.

Comment: I have posted the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor for an ArrayList doesn't add empty elements, it just sets its initial (internal) capacity, meaning that it will expect a certain amount of elements (avoiding resizing).

So, `new ArrayList<String>(20)` gives you an empty ArrayList with capacity 20.

This, combined with a scenario where `strings` doesn't contain all of the identifiers `CL`, `CR`, `L`, `R` would result in empty ArrayLists.